# Mysql GROUP BY first record and then filter on that record

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want the GROUP BY to pick the earliest StartSessionTime and then I want to filter based on the StartSessionTime, I tried various things, most recent being:

```
$sql_d = "SELECT  a.* FROM Session_Log  a INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT  ID, MIN(SessionStartTime) 
        FROM Session_Log GROUP BY ID 
     ) b 
     ON a.ID = b.ID 
        AND a.SessionStartTime = b.SessionStartTime 
     WHERE DATE(SessionStartTime) < ( '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL $b DAY ) 
      AND  DATE(SessionStartTime) >= ( '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL $a DAY )";
```

please help with the correct expression

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause looks fishy.  What are the values in `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: What error are you getting? What is desired output?

Comment: This is in a loop where $a & $b are getting assigned e.g. in one iteration, the values are 7 & 14

Comment: I don't like your `WHERE` clause and I think you should rephrase it.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for trying and giving pointers. I tried printing the error and noticed two issues in the expression. The code worked after fixing those issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign an alias to `MIN(SessionStartTime)` so you can reference it in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM FMan_Session_Log AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT DeviceID, MIN(SessionStartTime) AS MinSessionStartTime
    FROM FMan_Session_Log
) AS b ON a.DeviceID = b.DeviceID AND a.SessionStartTime = b.MinSessionStartTime
WHERE a.SessionStartTime >= DATE_ADD('2018-01-01', INTERVAL $a DAY)
AND a.SessionStartTime < DATE_ADD('2018-01-01, INTERVAL $b DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks. I arrived at the same solution by printing and looking at the errors. Any reason you are using a.SessionStartTime in first part of WHERE clause and b.SessionStartTime in the second part?

Comment: Can I do a further SORT BY a.SessionStartTime. If I add it at the end, I get an error

Comment: It's `ORDER BY`, not `SORT BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the errors. First the SessionStartTime was not defined for b. Second the SessionStartTime was ambiguous in WHERE clause

```
$sql_d = "SELECT  a.* FROM Session_Log  a INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT  ID, MIN(SessionStartTime) **as SessionStartTime**
        FROM Session_Log GROUP BY ID 
     ) b 
     ON a.ID = b.ID 
        AND a.SessionStartTime = b.SessionStartTime 
     WHERE DATE(a.SessionStartTime) < ( '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL $b DAY ) 
      AND  DATE(a.SessionStartTime) >= ( '2018-01-01' + INTERVAL $a DAY )";
```